# How to bind a public property to a WPF TextBox.Text property

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, binding

I've been struggling to bind a `TextBox.Text` to some object's public property but unfortunately I'm not quite there yet.

The actual XAML looks like:

```
<Window 
    <!-- skipped --> 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dotnet.Samples.Foobar"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Foobar x:Key="foobar" Foo="Lorem" Bar="Ipsum"
    </Window.Resources>
    <!-- skipped -->

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource foobar}, Path=Foo}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource foobar}, Path=Bar}">
        <!-- skipped -->
</Window>
```

With the data provider object being as simple as:

```
public class Foobar
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public Foobar()
    {

    }
}
```

I guess I'm sort of confused with WPF's various binding options and I'm probably mixing them up so any advice will be definitely appreciated.

**EDIT** -- All bindings are working ok, the remaining challenge is notifying changes from the Model to the ViewModel (the other way around works). I've committed the 'broken' code to an alternative repo:
 http://nanotaboada.svn.beanstalkapp.com/dotnet/trunk/Dotnet.Samples.Rijndael/

Feel free to checkout and I'd be very happy to hear about any feedback about this. Thanks much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML binding engine isn't finding an appropriate constructor to use, even though your constructor method parameters are optional.  Therefore, you'll either have to pass in the values for the constructor, or create a parameterless constructor which sets the value of Foo to a default value, or don't use the ObjectDataProvider at all, and create an instance of your type directly as a resource.

```
...
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...

<!-- Either create an instance of your type, and you can initialise the property values, this will require a default parameterless constructor -->
<abc:Foobar x:Key="foobar2" Foo="Foo" />

<!-- or pass the optional parameter values into your existing constructor -->
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="foobar" ObjectType="{x:Type abc:Foobar}">
  <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    <system:String>Foo</system:String>
    <system:String>Bar</system:String>
  </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Note that you'll only need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if your bindings are going to be invalidated in code, and you need to notify the UI.  If you aren't happy implementing this interface on your model types, then you can do this on your view models (assuming you're using MVVM), but then you'll need to find another mechanism to notify your view models when your model values change.

Comment: @devdigital: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation! The type instantiation/construction via `Window.Resources` works okay on the (I'm updating the original code) but still, the 'POCO' object is not getting their properties set. Let me guess -- should I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No, you wouldn't need to in this case - a notification of a property change is only required to notify the UI that a change has been made in code, not the other way around.  Are you sure the setters aren't being fired?  By default, the TextBox will only update the property on lost focus.  If you want to change this behaviour to update the property as you type in the TextBox, you'll need to set the UpdateSourceTrigger property value in the binding expression to PropertyChanged.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

Comment: @devdigital: Thanks again for your reply -- I've tried both `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and `Mode=TwoWay` with no better luck.

Comment: Are you able to supply a simple example which replicates the behaviour?

Comment: @devdigital: Sure, I've been trying to refactor this project: http://dotnetsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/57409 to implement bindings, naturally the code that motivates my question has not been committed but I guess I could drop the current working set somewhere?

Comment: If you could host the currently failing code somewhere and provide a link, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

This looks fine except that I don't think the ObjectDataProvider is capable of reading default parameters. Try creating a Foobar constructor that has no arguments whatsoever.

Failing that, can you give us the error you're seeing?

Comment: @Rob: thanks for the comment -- currently it compiled ok and there is no error but <code>TextBox.Text</code> is not showing any value so i'd go ahead and try without default parameters.

Comment: @Rob: I've just tried removing the defaults and constructing the object but didn't work.

Comment: +1, this should be working. @Nano Taboada: Did you set Foo to something in the constructor without parameters?

Comment: @Rob: Both recommendations from @devdigital for the data object provider worked (instance of the type as a `Resource` and `ObjectDataProvider` with `MethodParameters`), meaning the `TextBox` controls are displaying the binded values, but, the problem is that apparently there's something wrong/missing with such initialization/construction from WPF as the `Foobar` object properties are getting `null` values. Thanks for the comment and please let me know if I've expressed the case clearly.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "not quite there"? Everything looks fine to me except you're missing change notification in your `Foobar` class. Change it so that it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly and everything should work fine.

Comment: @Kent, thanks for the comment, by "not quite there" I mean "it doesn't work as expected" and I'll try your suggestion although I'm not sure if I should be adding System.ComponentModel interfaces to a class that has nothing to do with UI -- there should be another way to do it.

Comment: @Nano: `System.ComponentModel` has nothing to do with UI.

Comment: @Kent: "The `System.ComponentModel` namespace provides classes that are used to implement the run-time and design-time behavior of **components** and **controls**." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.aspx

Comment: @Nano: I meant nothing to do with a specific UI technology. ie. you're not tying your components to WPF. How do you expect WPF to know when a property has changed if there is no notification mechanism?

Comment: @Kent - because *historically*, it is the PropertyDescriptor mechanism (aka System.ComponentModel) that provided data-binding against arbitrary models (including custom models). Typically via the PropertyDescriptor recognising the `*Changed` pattern, but in theory by any random implementation - all exposed in the component-model. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is in many ways more limited... But my point being : there is a strong established relationship between component-model and UI.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with the parameters in the constructor.  If you really need them you can write it like this:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="foobar" ObjectType="{x:Type abc:Foobar}" MethodName="Foobar1">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:String>my_param</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

Which will also need this added: `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

And then the Foobar class will be this:

```
public class Foobar
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public Foobar Foobar1(string param1 = "foo", string param2 = "bar")
    {
        Foobar f = new Foobar();
        f.Foo = param1;
        f.Bar = param2;
        return f;
    }
}
```

Get rid of / add params in the XAML as you need.